# What is this dense erect sculpture-like bluish conifer?

Tags: identification, leaves, conifers

Actually, there are two of the same species:

[image]

They are 5m high at this time.

[image]

Needles/scales are really small:

[image]

[image]

This is in zone 8a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks similar to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaecyparis_lawsoniana.  Mine is ‘Blue Surprise’, quite blue indeed, and a favorite.

[Edit]
My guess is foliage differs between cultivars.  See my specimen at https://www.flickr.com/gp/157309556@N05/qH50MU.  Note the original tag says "foliage is juvenile".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: It would be nice to take a photo of the foliage of your tree, similar to photos in my question, and than insert these photos inline in the answer.

Comment: Habit of your tree  is definitely similar tho the habit of the tree from the wuestion, although I think your tree is a smaller cultivar, but still the same style of the crown.

Comment: Thanks for foliage pictures, I took the liberty to edit your post and place three pics inline, for easier access of future readers.